# What is wrong with my filter method on this selector?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

It is always returning an empty array.
It should only return ids and titles where the id of the drawsTRFormIdAndTitleSelector is === the transactionRequestFormId of the drawTRSelector

```
export const idAndTitleSelector = createSelector(
  drawTRSelector,
  drawsTRFormIdAndTitleSelector,
  (transactionRequests, idAndTitle) =>
    idAndTitle.filter(
      ({ id }) => id === transactionRequests.transactionRequestFormId
    )
);
```

drawTRSelector returns an array of objects that looks like:

```
[{
  id: "1",
  number: "1",
  transactionRequestFormId: "1",
}]
```

drawsTRFormIdAndTitleSelector returns an array of objects that looks like:

```
[{
  id: "1",
  title: "TR All Others",
}]
```

Comment: `transactionRequests.transactionRequestFormId.includes` will return a boolean.  You're comparing that boolean against `id`, so that will always return `false` unless `id` is `true` or `false`.

Comment: i see, i'll update my original post to show the other method ive tried

Comment: After the update, I see `drawTRSelector` will give you an array, so if `transactionRequests` is an array then `transactionRequests.transactionRequestFormId` isn't likely to have a value.  Did you mean to access the first entry of it maybe?  Some good old `console.log` lines will help you figure this out.

Comment: no, unfortunately i need to check all entries, not just the first

Comment: this is a simplified example, but each array can have multiple objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
const drawTRSelectorIds = createSelector(
  [drawTRSelector],
  (items) => items.map(({ id }) => id)
);
export const idAndTitleSelector = createSelector(
  drawTRSelectorIds,
  drawsTRFormIdAndTitleSelector,
  (ids, idAndTitle) =>
    idAndTitle.filter(({ id }) => ids.includes(id))
);
```

Comment: that was it, tyvm